# Do I have to start a multilingual site with a precise Language

Tags: i18n-l10n

I run Drupal 8.7.8 and tried to make it multilingual.
Is it important in which language you start?
I think I once stated with English and changed to German
I have some problems, because some text is really not translatable.
Some Nodes show the language selector others don't specially nodes that I have translated via the UI

Any Help.
Where could I get hel.
Thanks

Comment: Is this a public site?

Comment: "I think I once stated with English and changed to German I have some problems" Can you tell us what those problems were?

Comment: Till today I had problems to get back to the translated content. It always jumped back to the German content. I just managed to fix this today.
I observed that there where wrong stings in the SOURCE STRING

ST
Languages -> Sprachen

but there is also
ST
Sprachen --> Sprachen

where could I change that ??

Thanks Lothar